# How to resolve [Errno 13] Permission denied error in python

Tags: python, django, gmail-api

While saving the file it is throwing following error [Errno 13] Permission denied

I am trying to save the file in the current working directory but it is not saving

```
file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(i['body']['data'] .encode('UTF-8'))
store_dir = os.getcwd()
path = ''.join([store_dir, i['filename']])
f = open(path, 'w')
f.write(file_data)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
os.path.join(store_dir, i['filename'])
```

Comment: The error you are fixing would not cause a `[Errno 13] Permission denied`.

Comment: Did you actually test that?  becuase I did and got: `TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'`

Comment: @StephenRauch yes i did test it....`i['filename']` will be string and then it is working and creating an invalid path...I am using python 2.7

Comment: @vks  *it will because original join of OP results in invalid path* this is not quite correct, if fact, there is no way `path = ''.join([store_dir, i['filename']])` resulting in an invalid path.

Comment: python 2.7?  in 2019?  Don't do that...  However, passing a list to join to Python 2.7 still dies, but with a different message.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda suppose you have directory `RAY` and you want to create a file in it....now OP's code will try to create a file in a directory above `RAY` and so i assume he might not be having permission in that `dir`

Comment: @StephenRauch no there is no error....i just ran the code...`import os
store_dir = os.getcwd()
path = ''.join([store_dir, "abc"])
print path`

Comment: @vks You're tight about that. Is just that the OP not just need to use `os.path.join` he also needs the outcomming path to have to write permissions. If the working directory where '/'  there is a very big chance to receive a `Permission denied error` even using your answer.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda u r correct...but i assumed OP must be having permission in current directory at least that is why he must be trying...but yes my assumption may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

#### How to handle (or ... avoid?) [Errno 13] Permission denied?

Simple, write to a path where you have write permissions.

This:

```
path = ''.join([store_dir, i['filename']])
```

might be resulting in a path you don't have write permissions, @vks answer is a better way to get the correct path using your approach

```
os.path.join(store_dir, i['filename'])
```

, however ...

#### If you want to save your file in the current working directory...

... you only have to provide the file name, no `os` fancy magic is necessary.

```
file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(i['body']['data'] .encode('UTF-8'))
f = open("filename", 'w')
f.write(file_data)
f.close
```

**But be aware**, the user executing this script (as well as yours) has to have write permissions in that directory.